# How to use seed.rb to selectively populate development and/or production databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, environment

I am using seed.rb to populate both my development and production database. I usually populate the first with dummy data and the latter with the real minimal data that my app needs to run (e.g. the first user and so on).

How can I specify in seed.rb for what environment each data is?

Given that I know "group" to be a Gemfile method, I'd like to achieve the same behavior for seed.rb.

E.g. I'd like to write something like this in my seed.rb:

```
group :development do 
  # development specific seeding code
end

group :production do 
  # production specific seeding code
end

# non-specific seeding code (it always runs)
```

This to be able to call both the development-specific and the non-specific code with

```
$ rake db:seed
```

And to call both the production-specific and the non-specific code with:

```
$ rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production
```

Thank you

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`seeds.rb` is just a plain ruby file, so there are several ways you could approach this.  How about a case statement?

```
# do common stuff here

case Rails.env
when "development"
   ...
when "production"
   ...
end
```

Comment: can you provide more detail? Once you code it in, what commands do you use? How do you ensure only the changes go to the production database, and not wipe out all the other data unspecified (target database may think you want to wipe out other data if the seed for that is empty) etc.

Comment: @ahnbizcad you ensure it through the `config/database.yml` file. You set the production database target there, as well as development database.

Answer (score 46):

Another approach could be creating:

```
db/seeds/development.rb
db/seeds/production.rb
db/seeds/any_other_environment.rb
```

Then in `db/seeds.rb`:

```
# Code you want to run in all environments HERE
# ...
load(Rails.root.join( 'db', 'seeds', "#{Rails.env.downcase}.rb"))
```

Then write the code you want to run for each environment in the respective file.

Comment: nice. found this useful however i didn't want to seed test so you need to either have an empty seed/test.rb file or you can trap the file not found (along with other errors) so it doesn't terminate the tests.

Comment: Hey! If anyone is interested in a bit more detail on this method, I've just published an article on my blog all about this method — [Split your database seeds.rb by Rails environment](https://railsnotes.xyz/blog/split-seeds-rb-by-rails-environment)

Answer (score 20):

another approach, quite similar to @fabro's answer:
add a folder seeds to `db/` with the environment names and another named common.rb, so you get something like:

```
db/seeds/common.rb
db/seeds/development.rb
db/seeds/staging.rb
db/seeds/production.rb
```

than, in your `seed.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ['common', Rails.env].each do |seedfile|
    seed_file = "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds/#{seedfile}.rb"
    if File.exists?(seed_file)
      puts "- - Seeding data from file: #{seedfile}"
      require seed_file
    end
  end
end
```

I perfer running the seed in one transaction

Comment: That delicious moment when something older than two weeks is still relevant and helpful. Gotta love the maturity of Rails

Comment: @zcserei *years