# How should test and seed data be separated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, automated-tests

Is it up to me to write my own system, use a 3rd party solution, or does Rails offer a way to separate my test data from my seed data?

I'm aware of seeds.rb, and that it's just like a regular ruby file. I'd like to store seed/fixture data in something like yaml or json, but also to have my test data be randomly generated or purpose generated (to fail) somewhere separate from the seed data.

Comment: Too many answers. FactoryGirl, support fixtures, roll your own, have seed data by environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define separate seed files for your database, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808471/ruby-on-rails-way-to-create-different-seeds-file-for-environments).

I think what you really want is either [fixtures](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Fixtures.html) or factories, such as the [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) Gem.

Factories and fixtures allow you to define sample model data that is independent of your database state and designed for your tests.

For example, if you wanted a fixture to help you test a validation on a User model, you could have the following users.yml file

```
bob:
  name: bob
  birthday: 1989-11-12
```

Then, in your test, you could use the fixture:

```
test "should validate with name" do
  bob = users(:bob)
  assert bob.valid?
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that link. That's not a complete solution, but it really is super succinct way of handling different environments. I'll play with fixtures too. Thanks!